# change itemname: "*" to parent folder of the file [Azure Data Factory]

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can I get the the folder name of the file in the Get MetaData function.

As itemname I get this as result "*", since I have a wildcard in the connection settings of the source dataset. The folder structure is like this: project/location/file and would like to have location passed aswell.

Is it possible to pass like '/location/file.tdms' or pass the location in the next step which is an iteration (ForEach)?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can ignore that wildcard in data set. If we don't mention any value for file or folder it's going to bring all folder or file details. If your aim is to copy files from folder, you don't need a get meta data activity. Simply mention container/folder/* and then add additional column in source to capture file path using $$filepath system variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the project folder name under the container as shown below and use the `Get Metadata` activity to get the list of folders under the Project folder.

[image]

1. Select **Child items** under **Field list** in the `Get Metadata` activity to get the folders under the project.

[image]

**The output of Get Metadata**:

[image]

2. Connect the `Get Metadata` activity output to the `ForEach` activity to loop the **current item** and get the files under the **location** folder.

[image]

3. Add an activity in **ForEach** to process the files of the **current ForEach item**. Here as an example, I am using another `Get Metadata` activity to show the list of files under location (output folder of Get Metadata1).

- Create another source dataset locating to same container/project, and parameterize the directory & filename.

[image]

4. In **Get Metadata2**, pass the current item name (output folder name of Get Metadata1) in directory parameter and specify **(*)** in file_name parameter to get the files list with the **Filed list** as **child items**.

[image]

**The output of Get Metadata2:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the guide, It was exactly what I was looking for.